# PyQt5 QTreeWidget - отработка клика по элементам дерева

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, сигналы-слоты, qtreeview

Я строю дерево и вывожу его в `QTreeWidget` (https://clip2net.com/s/450X4zs) таким образом:

```
def treeRubrics(self):
    self.treeList.setHeaderLabels(['Записи'])
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    __sortingEnabled = self.treeList.isSortingEnabled()
    self.treeList.setSortingEnabled(False)
    level = 1
    child = 0
    num = -1
    rubrics = NotebookRubrics()
    tree = rubrics.tree()
    for data in tree:
        if int(data.level) == 0:
            continue
        if int(data.level) <= level:
            item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeList)
        else:
            item_1 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)

        if int(data.level) <= level:
            num += 1
            child = 0
            self.treeList.topLevelItem(num).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", str(data.name)))
        else:
            self.treeList.topLevelItem(num).child(child).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", str(data.name)))
            child += 1
            
        level = int(data.level)

    self.treeList.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
```

У меня вопрос - как мне реализовать передачу `data.id` по клику в элементы дерева.

Я пытался так:

```
    ...    
        else:
            self.treeList.topLevelItem(num).child(child).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", str(data.name)))
            child += 1

        self.treeList.itemClicked.connect(self.msgBar(data.id))

        level = int(data.level)

    self.treeList.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
```

Т.е. в конце цикла добавления элемента в дерево вставлю

```
self.treeList.itemClicked.connect(self.msgBar(data.id))
```

Но тогда при клике на любой элемент списка возвращается `ID` последней записи.

Как сделать, что бы для каждого элемента списка дерева проставлялся свой `ID` и он же возвращался при клике на него?

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимально-воспроизводимый пример демонстрирующий вашу проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Плохая практика не публиковать минимально-воспроизводимый пример демонстрирующий вашу проблему.

Я могу только предположить, что вам надо заменить две строки:

```
        ...
        # self.treeList.itemClicked.connect(self.msgBar(data.id))
        self.treeList.itemClicked.connect(lambda item, column, i=data.id: self.msgBar(item, column, i)) # +
        ...

    def msgBar(self, item, column, i):   # +
        print(item, column, i)
    ...
```

---

Вы также можете проверить мой пример:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

tree = {
'parent 1': ["child 1-1"],
'child 1-2': [],
'child 1-3': ["child 1-1-1"],
'children 2-1': ["..."],
"parent 2": ["..."],
"parent 3": [],
"parent 4": []     
}


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tree_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tree_view)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.populateTree(tree, model.invisibleRootItem())
        self.tree_view.setModel(model)
        model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Записи')
        self.tree_view.expandAll()
        self.tree_view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)

    def populateTree(self, children, parent):
        for child in children:
            child_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(child)
            parent.appendRow(child_item)
            if isinstance(children, dict):
                self.populateTree(children[child], child_item)

    def onSelectionChanged(self, *args):
        for sel in self.tree_view.selectedIndexes():
            val = "/"+sel.data()
            while sel.parent().isValid():
                sel = sel.parent()
                val = "/"+ sel.data()+ val
            print(val)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: S.Nick спасибо вам, но теперь при клике выводятся все ID, (https://clip2net.com/s/451vpBp) если смотреть в "i", column так же выводится несколько раз и везде равен 0, то же и с item, а мне надо вывести только конкретный ID этой записи